# Redux Framework logo upload after hide Wordpress title and description

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks, redux-framework

I'm using Redux Framework for Wordpress theme. 
Then upload logo from redux options panel.

```
<img src="<?php global $redux_demo; echo '' . $redux_demo['opt-media']['url'];
?>" />
```

If upload image logo after how to hide wordpress title and description ?

```
<span class="site-title">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
</span>
<h4 class="site-desc"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h4>
```

Redux field:

```
array(
                        'id'       => 'opt-media',
                        'type'     => 'media',
                        'title'    => __( 'Web Fonts', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                        'compiler' => 'true',
                        'mode'     => false,
                        // Can be set to false to allow any media type, or can also be set to any mime type.
                        'desc'     => __( 'Basic media uploader with disabled URL input field.', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                        'subtitle' => __( 'Upload any media using the WordPress native uploader', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                        'hint'     => array(
                            //'title'     => '',
                            'content' => 'This is a <b>hint</b> tool-tip for the webFonts field.<br/><br/>Add any HTML based text you like here.',
                        )
                    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if($redux_demo['opt-media']['url']!='')
    {
    ?>
       <img src="<?php global $redux_demo; echo '' . $redux_demo['opt-media']['url'];?>" />
   <?php  }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <span class="site-title">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
             </a>
    </span>
    <h4 class="site-desc"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h4>
   <?php
    }
```

Hope this will work for you. I have faced same problem and solved for my project. Please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: <?php global $redux_demo; ?>  did you give this line on the top of this

Comment: Wow, I missed this line. Working cool. Solved my question. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you want to hide WordPress title and description after upload logo then change your code to like this

```
     <?php global $redux_demo; ?>
        <?php if ($redux_demo['opt-media']['url'] != ' ') { ?>
             <img src="<?php  echo '' . $redux_demo['opt-media']['url']; ?>" />

         <?php } else { ?>
             <span class="site-title">
               <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
           </span>
              <h4 class="site-desc"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h4> 
     <?php } ?>
```

I think it will work fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm getting syntax error: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2gv5xro.jpg How to solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Sorry its my mistake so i update this code snippet please check again

Comment: Hey its working fine. But when I remove image logo from redux panel  doesn't show title and description. What can I do ? :)